# can't pass data in to delete request with Vue-Resource

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-resource

im getting problem with passing data in to delete request with Vue-resource. Server is reciving blank object without data. There is some code:

Front-end with Vue.js and Vue-resourcer

```
deleteArticle: function(tit){
  console.log(tit);
  this.$http.delete('http://192.168.0.52:8080/article',{'title':'123'}).then((res)=>{
    this.refresh();
    console.log(res.data);
  }).catch((e)=>{console.log(e)});
}
```

Back-end with node.js route using express.js API.

```
app.delete('/article', (req,res)=>{
 var body = _.pick(req.body,['title']);
 console.log(req.body); //printing blank object from request
 Article.findByTitleAndRemove(body.title).then((doc)=>{
  res.status(200).send(`Deleted Article with title ${doc.title}`)
 }).catch((e)=>{
  console.log(e);
  res.status(400).send(e);
 })
})
```

This route works with postman.

Comment: does `console.log(tit);` logs to the console ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.$http.delete('http://192.168.0.52:8080/article', { params: { title: 123 } }).then(res => {
    this.refresh();
    console.log(res.data);
}).catch((e)=>{console.log(e)});
```

Update: this is how this works for me in node:

```
app.delete('/article', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query.title); 
});
```

[image]

Comment: Printing still empty object :(

Comment: I updated my answer to demonstrate printing the query in node :)